# after I fixed the error Route [Login] not defined, I can't log in even though I use the correct email and password

Tags: laravel-8

this is `web.php`

```
Route::get('/login', [LoginController::class, 'index'])->name('login')->middleware('guest');
Route::post('/login', [LoginController::class, 'authenticate']);
Route::post('/logout', [LoginController::class, 'logout']);
```

this is my `LoginController`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('login.index', [
            'title' => 'Login'
        ]);
    }

    public function authenticate(Request $request)
    {
        $credentials = $request->validate([
            'email' => 'required|email:dns',
            'password' => 'required'
        ]);

        if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
            $request->session()->regenerate();
            return redirect()->intended('/admin');
        }

        return back()->with('loginError', 'Login anda gagal !');
    }

    public function logout(Request $request)
    {
        Auth::logout();

        $request->session()->invalidate();

        $request->session()->regenerateToken();

        return redirect('/login');
    }
}
```

this is my login view

```
<main class="form-signin">

  @if (session()->has('Sukses'))
  <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
    {{ session('Sukses') }}
    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button>
  </div>
  @endif

  @if (session()->has('loginError'))
  <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
    {{ session('loginError') }}
    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button>
  </div>
  @endif

  <form action="/login" method="post">
    @csrf

    <img class="mb-4" src="/img/discord.png" alt="" width="100" height="99">
    <h1 class="h3 mb-3 fw-normal">Please Login</h1>

    <div class="form-floating">
      <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" id="email" placeholder="name@example.com" autofocus required value="{{ old('email') }}">
      <label for="email">Masukkan Email</label>
      @error('email')
        <div class="invalid-feedback">
            {{ $message }}
        </div>
      @enderror
          
    </div>
    <div class="form-floating">
      <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password" required>
      <label for="password">Password</label>
    </div>

    <button class="w-100 btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="submit">Login</button>
    </form>
    <small class="d-block text-center mt-3">Not have any account? <a href="/register">Register here</a></small>
    <p class="mt-5 mb-3 text-muted">&copy; 2022</p>
</main>
```

Comment: Can you provide more info on login view

Comment: Firstly, Make sure that the password that you log in with is hashed also, try to search about the user with the given email then check if the password is correct like so, `$user = \App\Models\user::where('email', $request->email)->first();dd(Hash::check($user->password, $request->password));`

Comment: where should i put that code?